# Optional ASP Hyperlink

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, hyperlink

I have some company names within a Repeater, and each of the companies may or may not have a link.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CompanyName" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

If I set the NavigateUrl to null, it still renders the `<a>` tag in the HTML. If I set it to Visible=False, it does not render the company name. Is it possible to remove the HyperLink but keep the company name if there is no NavigateUrl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CompanySiteUrl") as string) %>' />
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CompanySiteUrl") %>' Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CompanySiteUrl") as string) %>'>
    <%# Eval("CompanyName") %>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. One would be to build up the html using a code block

```
<%#IIF(CompanyName <> "", "<a href='" & Eval("CompanySiteUrl") & "'>" & Eval("CompanyName") & "</a>", Eval("CompanyName"))%>
```

Or you could create a public method that you can call and then just build up the html in the method

```
<%#BuildCompanyUrl(Eval("CopmanySiteUrl"), Eval("CompanyName"))%>

Public Function BuildCompanyUrl(ByVal CompanySiteUrl as string, ByVal Copmanyname as string) As String
     ' build up the logic here and return the html
    return "<a href="......."
End Function
```